# check recipient addresses with Exim backup MX

Tags: debian, exim

I want to configure backup MX with Exim on Debian, using `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` I've set this:

```
#update-exim4.conf.conf
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='xxx'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains='domain_to_relay'
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost=''
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname=''
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

it accepts all mail going to the domain_to_relay, but I want to reject mail for unknown addresses (maintaining a list of known addresses) so it does not become a backscatter, how can I configure this?

The equivalent in postfix would be

```
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this adding this to `update-exim4.conf.conf`

```
CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE=/etc/exim4/custom_acl
```

creating the custom ACL file `/etc/exim4/custom_acl`:

```
deny !recipients = /etc/exim4/recipients_whitelist
```

and creating the list of known addresses on `/etc/exim4/recipients_whitelist`

```
user1@domain.tld
user2@domain.tld
...
```